# Why is the alt key sticky in Chrome on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard

In Chrome on Windows7 tapping alt selects the hamburger menu, which can then be navigated with arrow keys. If I tap alt without noticing it and start typing nothing happens, which is confusing, so I would like for this to not happen.

To be clear,
- I do not have sticky keys enabled. I tried enabling Sticky Keys just to be sure, and it was much more obvious than this problem and did not have the same behavior as what I'm seeing now.

- I do use some extensions, but I disabled everything in incognito mode and still had the same issue.
- This is the left alt key on a US-format keyboard, specifically for a Thinkpad x230.
- I am not sure if Chrome is picking up keypresses it shouldn't or if I'm clumsy, but because I use an IME for language input I push alt frequently.
- This doesn't seem to be affecting applications besides Chrome.
- Chrome version is 47.0.2526.73 m.

Any advice on how to keep this from happening would be appreciated.

Comment: `This doesn't seem to be affecting applications besides Chrome.` Are you sure Alt doesn't affect other programs? Try starting Notepad or Wordpad end press Alt just once. Can you still type? In any Windows-program I know Alt selects the menu. Also the case for Chrome (seeing that the hamburger is a "menu"). Just press Alt one more time and you can type again. I don't think this behavior can be disabled.

Comment: Ah, you're right - I mostly work just in the browser and an SSH terminal and for some reason the effect isn't very noticeable in the terminal. Thanks for clarifying that for me!